# Cannot install mint 18 on windows 10 Hyper V

Tags: windows-10, linux-mint, hyper-v

I am trying to install Mint 18 64 bit in hyper V running on windows 10 (I am not trying to use dual boot nor unix-in-windows).

I tried following the instructions [here](http://www.technig.com/install-linux-mint-on-hyper-v/).  I do not get the cinnamon desktop.  Instead I get a BusyBox shell.

I've given the hyper-v machine 4096MB ram and 250GB of diskspace.

So far, nothing I have found via google search has turned up any answers to the problem I am experiencing.

Any ideas what I need to do to get started?

Comment: I'm adding this as comment until someone says its ok to answer.  I must have had a bad ISO.  I downloaded the ISO from a different source and it worked just fine.  There was a difference in ISO size as well as function.

Comment: You've been around the Stack Exchange for 6 yrs.  Why do you suddenly think you need permission to post an answer?  Go for it.

Comment: @fixer1234 because I still get dinged for doing something wrong by one of the moderators--comments deleted, posts closed for one reason or another, etc etc.....frustrating imo.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I have solved this myself.   I must have had a bad ISO. I downloaded the ISO from a different source and it worked just fine. There was a difference in ISO size as well as function.

So, if you have this problem, I would suggest starting with a different ISO.